# Replacing Nagios HTTP with custom (select/poll driven) daemon?

Tags: https, redis, nagios

I have a a Nagios configuration which is performing a number of tests on a few hundred nodes; one of these is a variant of `check_http`.  It's not configured to --enable-embedded-perl (ePN)  but we'll be changing that soon.  Even with ePN enabled I'm concerned about the model where each execution of this Perl HTTP+SSL check will be handling only a single target.

I'd like to write a simple *select()* (or *poll()* / *epoll()*) driven daemon which creates connections to multiple targets concurrently, reads the results and spits out results in a form that's useable to Nagios as if it were results from a passive check.

Is there a guide to how one could accomplish this?  What's the interface or API for providing batched check updates to Nagios?

One hack I'm considering would be to have my daemon update a Redis store (with a key for each target, and a short expiration time) and replace `check_http` with a very small, lightweight GET of the local Redis instance on the key (the GET would either get the actual results for Nagios or a "(nil)" response which will be treated as if the HTTP connection had timed out.

However, I'm also a bit skeptical of my idea since I'd think someone has already something like this by now.

(BTW: I'm ready to be convinced to switch to something like [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org/) or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) or [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) or [OpenNMS](http://opennms.org/) ... pretty much anything that will scale better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to whether or not to let Nagios handle the scheduling and checks, I'll leave that to you as it varies depending on your version of Nagios (newer versions can run these checks concurrently), and why you want a separate daemon for it. egarding versioning of Nagios, version 3 IIRC uses concurrent checks, and scales thusly to larger node counts than you report.

However, I can answer the Redis route concept as I've done it with Postfix queue stats and TTFB tracking for web sites.

Setting up the check using Python with the curl and multiprocessing modules is fairly straightforward as is dumping it into Redis. An expiration of I'd say no more than the interval would be a solid idea to keep the DB from growing. I'd recommend tis value be no more (or possibly just less than) the check interval to avoid grabbing stale check results. If the currently running check hasn't completed and the Redis-to-Nagios check runs, pulling in the previous check, you can miss failed checks.

For the Redis-To-Nagios check a simple redis-cli+bash scripting or Python check to pull the data for a given host, returning OK or otherwise depending on your data is fairly simple and would run quickly enough.

I'd recommend running the Redis instance on the Nagios check server to ensure minimum latency and avoid a network issue causing false alerts on your checks. I would also recommend a Nagios check on your Redis instance and the checking daemon. Make the check_http replacement check dependent on the Redis and http_check daemons running. THus you have a dependency chain as follows:

```
Redis -> http_checkd -> http_check_replacement
```

This will prevent false alerts on http_check_replacement by identifying the problem. For example, if your redis_checkd dies you get alerted to that, not 200+ "failed http_check_replacement" ones.

Also, since your data in Redis is by definition transient, I would disable the disk persistence. No need to write to disk when the data is constantly rotating.

On a side note, I would recommend, if using libcurl, you pull statistics from libcurl about how long it takes to get the connection open and how long the server to to respond (Time To First Byte - TTFB) and take advantage of Nagios's ability to store check statistics. You may well reach a time when having that data is really handy for troubleshooting and performance analysis.

I have a CLI Tool I've written in C which does this and uploads it into a local Redis instance. It is fast - barely more than the time to get the URL. I'm expecting it be open sourced this week, I can add Nagios style output to it fairly easily. In fact, I think I'll do that in the next week or two.